# How can I display the word "Today" incase the DateTime is within today day

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code inside my razor view in my asp.net MVC web application

```
<span class="yellow"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.StartDate) </span>
```

The code displays the DateTime as is in the data base sch as `04/12/2013 05:05:30 AM`, which is fine, but how can I do some validation on my view, to display the word `"Today"` if the `DateTime.Date` equals today ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@if (item.StartDate.Date != DateTime.Today)
{
    <span class="yellow"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.StartDate) </span>
}
else
{
    <span class="yellow"> Today </span>
}
```